# Webhook receiver response

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, webhooks, receiver

I have a Webhook receiver with aspnet webapi and use this packages

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Common
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers
Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Generic
```

And this is my handler

```
Public Class GenericJsonWebHookHandler
    Inherits WebHookHandler

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Receiver = GenericJsonWebHookReceiver.ReceiverName
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal receiver As String, ByVal context As WebHookHandlerContext) As Task
        Dim data As JObject = context.GetDataOrDefault(Of JObject)()
        If data.HasValues Then
            'Do something
            Return Task.FromResult(True)
        Else
            'Here I want to return a Bad Request or a different that 200 OK
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

I want make some verification with the json I recieve and if fails I need to return a differente status that 200 OK, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very easy, if someone have the same problem here it is:

```
context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Some message")
Return Task.FromResult(True)
```